# Trying to format Google Analytics data ready for machine learning, need help looping through a list of values and create the same number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I am currently working with analytics data that features the landing page of users and I have already made the Gender and Age Bracket data friendly for machine learning via the following method:

```
age = dataset.pop('ga:userAgeBracket')
gender = dataset.pop('ga:userGender')
dataset['18-24'] = (age == '18-24') * 1.0
dataset['25-34'] = (age == '25-34') * 1.0
dataset['35-44'] = (age == '35-44') * 1.0
dataset['45-54'] = (age == '45-54') * 1.0
dataset['55-64'] = (age == '55-64') * 1.0
dataset['65+'] = (age == '65+') * 1.0
dataset['Male'] = (gender == 'male') * 1.0
dataset['Female'] = (gender == 'female') * 1.0
```

This method works fine for data that has only a few different variants.

However, ga:landingPagePath can potentially have an infinite number of data points and I was wondering if there is an easy way to loop through this and create the same column structure as I have with the other data points

Just for reference, this is how the dataset looks after I clean the gender and age column:
[image]

The number of unique URLs for this particular dataset with a REGEX filter I have in place is about 70+

Comment: Clarifying question: What do you mean by same column structure? A problem you'll run into down the road is sparsity. For example, you might have only 1 hit to a rare landing page (and you'll have a lot of these). You might think instead about creating classes based on the page path instead. So: example.com/books/book-1.html would get just the class "books". My opinion is you'll have to roll URL data up into a higher-level class.

Comment: Hi @Jarad, There is a filter in place to prevent obscure URLs from popping up in the pull from Analytics, so in total there are about 70+ URLs that I need to create columns for

Comment: Do you know about pd.get_dummies()? You could also use scikit-learn's label_binarize I believe.